# 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' when trying to concatenate a list of data frames into a single data drame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate a list of data frames (`dfList`) into a single, big data frame (`df`). I was hoping to use `df = pd.concat(dfList)` however I keep getting the following error:

```py
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I have read similar posts, but:

1. Most only deal with 2 data frames. My list has 150 data frames and so I am looking for a more automated (ideally without a for loop) solution; and
2. All the data frames in my list *should* have the same row index and column names so I don't understand the underlying problem here.

Thanks for your help in solving this problem!

Comment: You should add a little sample (mre, copy-&-pastable). What is the `concat`-axis - default? Have you tried `ignore_index=True`?

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest running this code and finding out where things go pear shaped

```
for i in range(1, len(dfList)):
    try:
        pd.concat(dfList[:i])
    except:
        print(i)
```